# D3js diagonal and Bezier curves

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to use `d3.svg.diagonal()` to create a Bezier curve. Someone could explain me how it works. I mean I don't understand the link between the mathematical definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve and the diagonal function with `source`, `target` and `projection`. Where are the control points?

Comment: Why -1? I think that there is no a direct link between the mathematics definition and the d3.svg.diagonal documention. Where are the tangents for instance?

Answer (score 0):

> > I mean I don't understand the link between the mathematical definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve and the diagonal function with source, target and projection. Where are the control points?

the projection converts the inputs (source and target) to coords (x,y) and output as an Array
default is a 1:1 projection, no change of the values.

```
//pseudocode:
var src = projection(source), 
    trg = projection(target);

var points = [
    src,
    [src[0], (src[1] + trg[1]) / 2],
    [trg[0], (src[1] + trg[1]) / 2],
    trg
]
```